# is there a way to change the time that notifications take to disappear?

Tags: notifications

I would like to change the time a notification takes to disappear, when I get mails in a row it fills the screen with notifications and it takes too long to disappear, i have to clone each one to make them go away

Answer (score 1):

Install "dconf editor"

Change property value of:

> Desktop > ibus > panel > auto-hide-timeout

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a setting for notifications' duration, but you can disable them on a per-app basis. Go to System Settings -> Notifications -> click Mail in the left pane -> disable Bubbles.